# c++ error "member function declared with 'override' does not override a base class member"

Tags: c++

I am learning/testing virtual functions. Below is my test code, and I got the following error and couldn't figure out why:

"member function declared with "override" does not override a base class member 
bool is_satified(Product* item) override{return item->color == color;}"

In specification, I have already defined "is_satisfied" as virtual. Could someone point out what is wrong here? Thanks!

```cpp
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

enum class Color {red, green, blue};
enum class Size {small, medium, large};

struct Product{
    string name;
    Color color;
    Size size;
};

template <typename T> struct Specification{
    virtual bool is_satisfied(T* item) = 0;
};

struct ColorSpecification: Specification<Product>{
    Color color;
    explicit ColorSpecification(const Color color): color{color} {}
    bool is_satified(Product* item) override{return item->color == color;}
};

int main(){
ColorSpecification green(Color::green);
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a typo:

```
is_satisfied
```

vs

```
is_satified
```

btw `using namespace std` is considered bad practice.

Comment: Thanks so much! Your reply solves my issue.